# SVG line X-axis without stretching

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an SVG like this one

```
<svg width="212" height="20" viewBox="0 0 212 20" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M202 11C202.552 11 203 10.5523 203 10C203 9.44772 202.552 9 202 9V11ZM9.29289 9.29289C8.90237 9.68342 8.90237 10.3166 9.29289 10.7071L15.6569 17.0711C16.0474 17.4616 16.6805 17.4616 17.0711 17.0711C17.4616 16.6805 17.4616 16.0474 17.0711 15.6569L11.4142 10L17.0711 4.34315C17.4616 3.95262 17.4616 3.31946 17.0711 2.92893C16.6805 2.53841 16.0474 2.53841 15.6569 2.92893L9.29289 9.29289ZM202 9L10 9V11L202 11V9Z" fill="#EF8460"/>
</svg>
```

Which is a line with an arrow head, exported from Figma.

I am curious is there any possible way with a single path like this to make this SVG scalable to the X-axis?

I want to replicate this behaviour, where the svg will adapt to the width of the container.

[image]

---

You can find a more simple line path in the example below:

```css
.container{
  width: 600px; /* : Modify this value to test container width  */
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    width="100%"
    height="auto"
    fill="none"
    viewBox="0 0 100 20"
    preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin"
    vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"
  >
    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="0" stroke="#EF8460" strokeWidth="8" />
    <!-- <rect width="100" height="20" fill="#EF8460" /> -->
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Easier with a line and a marker for the arrowhead